# distribution of values basis fixed percentage & summing up the values vertically

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have created the below table in excel and now i am looking to replicate the same in python.
[image: Excel Table]

- settled accounts are further distributed basis the fixed percentages for subsequent months in column  [image: % distribution]

I am looking to create the similar dataframe in python and have initiated with below approach :

```
data = {
    'Assigned Accounts': [1428, 1415, 1398, 1402, 1468, 1503, 1694],
    'Month': ['Jun-22', 'Jul-22', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-22', 'Oct-22', 'Nov-22', 'Dec-22']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Settled Accounts'] = int(data['Assigned Accounts']*0.17)

# Fixed percentage distribution
percentages = [0.46, 0.36, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01]

# Creating columns for subsequent months and distributing the settled debtors
months = ['Jun-22', 'Jul-22', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-22', 'Oct-22', 'Nov-22', 'Dec-22', 'Jan-23', 'Feb-23', 'Mar-23', 'Apr-23', 'May-23', 'Jun-23']

how it could be approached further.?
```

i am looking for final dataframe which gives the sum of columns vertically as below :

```
Month        Total
Jan - 23     350
Feb - 23     335
Mar - 23     343
Apr - 23     341 and so on
```

** Updated Question :**

for below dataframe what will be the change in approach :

```
data = {
    'Assigned Accounts': [674, 779, 812, 735, 753, 677, 628, 589, 570, 581, 550, 595, 596, 659, 754, 731, 739, 741, 766, 796, 752, 821, 818, 868, 850, 909, 927, 915],
    'Month': ['Jun-22', 'Jul-22', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-22', 'Oct-22', 'Nov-22', 'Dec-22', 'Jan-23', 'Feb-23', 'Mar-23', 'Apr-23', 'May-23', 'Jun-23', 'Jul-23', 'Aug-23', 'Sep-23', 'Oct-23', 'Nov-23', 'Dec-23', 'Jan-24', 'Feb-24', 'Mar-24', 'Apr-24', 'May-24', 'Jun-24', 'Jul-24', 'Aug-24', 'Sep-24']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

months: ['Jun-22', 'Jul-22', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-22', 'Oct-22', 'Nov-22', 'Dec-22', 'Jan-23', 'Feb-23', 'Mar-23', 'Apr-23', 'May-23', 'Jun-23', 'Jul-23', 'Aug-23', 'Sep-23', 'Oct-23', 'Nov-23', 'Dec-23', 'Jan-24', 'Feb-24', 'Mar-24', 'Apr-24', 'May-24', 'Jun-24', 'Jul-24', 'Aug-24', 'Sep-24']
```

rest the problem statement would remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to multiply each row value by your percentages and shift the values each month.

You can easily do this with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

*NB. In your picture, it looked like you used a ~23% factor (not 17%), I used that below for better comparison of the numbers.*

```
# 23% of initial value
df['Settled Accounts'] = df['Assigned Accounts'].mul(0.23).astype(int)

# create output array
tmp = np.full((len(df), len(months)), np.nan)
# indexer for rows
a = np.arange(len(df))
# indexer for shifted values
col = (a[:,None] + np.arange(len(percentages))).ravel()
m = col<len(a)
idx = np.repeat(a, len(percentages))[m]

# broadcast the multiplication by "percent"
tmp[idx, col[m]] =  (df['Settled Accounts'].to_numpy()[:,None]
                     * np.array(percentages)
                    ).ravel()[m].astype(int)

# convert to DataFrame
tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=df.index, columns=months)
# add sum as new row
tmp.loc['sum'] = tmp.sum()

out = df.join(tmp, how='outer')
```

Output:

```
     Assigned Accounts   Month  Settled Accounts  Jun-22  Jul-22  Aug-22  Sep-22  Oct-22  Nov-22  Dec-22  Jan-23  Feb-23  Mar-23  Apr-23  May-23  Jun-23
0               1428.0  Jun-22             328.0   150.0   118.0    19.0     9.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1               1415.0  Jul-22             325.0     NaN   149.0   117.0    19.0     9.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2               1398.0  Aug-22             321.0     NaN     NaN   147.0   115.0    19.0     9.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3               1402.0  Sep-22             322.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   148.0   115.0    19.0     9.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
4               1468.0  Oct-22             337.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   155.0   121.0    20.0    10.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN     NaN
5               1503.0  Nov-22             345.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   158.0   124.0    20.0    10.0     6.0     3.0     3.0     NaN
6               1694.0  Dec-22             389.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   178.0   140.0    23.0    11.0     7.0     3.0     3.0
sum                NaN     NaN               NaN   150.0   267.0   283.0   291.0   304.0   316.0   343.0   182.0    45.0    23.0    13.0     6.0     3.0
```

Comment: i have included few more Month in df as well as in months , after running the above code it gives this error :       1 # broadcast the multiplication by "percent"
----> 2 tmp[a, idx] =  (assigned_month['Settled Accounts'].to_numpy()
      3                 * np.array(percentages)[:,None]
      4                ).astype(int)

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,) (16,7)             --- what relevant changes should be made to encounter this..?

Comment: Can you update the question with this additional example? (keep the original as well) If this is too different, maybe ask a new question?

Comment: have updated the question. problem statement would remain the same.

Comment: @Romi there was an issue with the numpy indexing, I updated with a more robust method